# php, html - <label> changes, but <bgcolor> does not

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to change the background color of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLVXb.png) register page, but it's not changing, I change the [`<label>` and `<body>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnWz7.png) to something else... but only `<label>` changes.

I got this whole source code in the description of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C--mu07uhQw).

Answer (score 1):

The `bgcolor` attribute is old, very old. Your document is set in HTML5 (the `<!doctype html>` part). I'm not even sure if `bgcolor` is supported anymore. Try `style="background-color:yellow;"` instead :]